# Partition function in Non-equilibrium field theory in statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body, non-equilibrium

Consider a system that described by  the Hamiltonian $H(t)$, contains non-adiabatic time-dependent external fields and the evolution drives the system away from equilibrium.
Now the partition function $Z$ is given by-
\begin{equation}
Z = \dfrac{Tr\Big[U_{C}\rho(-\infty)\Big]}{Tr[\rho(-\infty)]}
\end{equation}
Where $U_{C}=U(-\infty,\infty)U(\infty,-\infty)$ and $C$ defined a closed contour (Schwinger-Keldysh contour)
and the expectation value of an observable is given by-
\begin{equation}
<O>(t)=\dfrac{i}{2} \lim_{V \to 0} \dfrac{\delta Z[V]}{\delta V(t)}
\end{equation}
Could you justify why this is the expression of the partition function and the expectation value in a non-equilibrium case?

Reference: Field Theory of Non-Equilibrium Systems, by Alex Kamenev.

Comment: I mean, a good chunk of the first chapter or so of Kamenev's book is spent deriving this result. What part of that was not clear?

Comment: I do not understand the expectation value expression. Could you please explain it?